# What's the benefit of using Adaptors over subclassing/wrapping Session in twisted.web?

Tags: python, twisted

It feels to me that using components/adapters is just adding extra bloat to handling sessions without much obvious benefit. It feels simpler to just subclass or wrap the session and use this subclass to generate sessions.
Maybe I am not seeing some obvious benefits of using components and adapters, so if anyone could explain this to me, please do.

Answer (score 1):

The session is basically a dictionary.  Adapters are the values you can put into it, and interfaces are the keys you use with them.

Subclassing comes with a bunch of problems, none of them specific to the web or session state handling.  It mixes lots of implementation concerns together that don't need to be mixed.  A dictionary, on the other hand, is just a collection of state - exactly what is called for when it comes to tracking the state needed for a session.

Your alternate idea, to "just subclass or wrap the session and use this subclass to generate sessions" is very general and somewhat ambiguous, so I can't explain in detail why the current system might be better than it.  If you want to describe your idea in complete detail (perhaps by providing an implementation), then perhaps someone can critique it.